# Highlight the active link in a navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder if my script is all right. Please review my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Menu</title>
<style>
ul {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
li {display:inline;}
a.active {background:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    if (document.links[i].href == document.URL) {
        document.links[i].className = 'active';
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should highlight the current page link in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `querySelectorAll`

Here's another approach, if you don't mind older browsers. You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead of `document.links`. That way, [you end up with a smaller result set](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmb54/) rather than all links, and save you CPU cycles for running the loop.

In this case, we get only those links that have the same `href` value as the current document url:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+document.URL+'"]');
```

However, note the [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) and there are quirks across implementations.

### Not all links need `active`

Now if you think about it, not all links with the `document.URL` need to have `active`. Say you have `active` set the font to `2em`. If you get all links that point to the same page, they'd be `2em` in size, regardless of where they are in the page!

Most likely, you only need it for the primary navigation. Consider adding a class to further refine the result set.

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/about">About</a></li>
</ul>

// Getting only the links that are in .navigation
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation a[href="'+document.URL+'"]');

// More specific CSS
.navigation a.active {background:red;}
```

## `className`

Now you have to note that setting `className` *replaces it* with the value, [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/u7VE2/2/). If the links you have happen to have existing classes (and styles that come with them), your script will unintentionally remove their styles due to the replaced `className`.

What you can do is get the existing `className` value, split them by spaces (multiple class names are separated by spaces), append your class name, join them back *and then* change the value, [like I did here](http://jsfiddle.net/u7VE2/1/):

```
var element = document.getElementById('change');
var classNames = element.className.split(' ');
classNames.push('huge');
element.className = classNames.join(' ');
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use these for `<a>` tag

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OCUYALI/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is mainly focused on the `script` tag.

Comment: what do you want with script

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.